# Is it possible to overwrite/replace header location data?

Tags: php

I have a fairly complex PHP script which runs on top of a commercially available PHP script (which cannot be edited).

The underlying product every so often does a header:location forward.

My script which runs on top of the commercial product also sometimes forwards a URL based on the header:location principle.

Problem occurs when both the scripts decide to place a header:location is, so the page actually has 'duplicate headers' which is blocked by chrome.

The solutions to this I can think of (without being able to change the core code of the underlying php script) are to either (A) Check it a location header has already been sent, if so, dont send a new one  or (B)  overwrite a header-location that has been issued.

Are any of these two options possible?

Comment: `void header ( string $string [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] )`

Comment: See also: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php

Answer (score 0):

Once you have decided to throw another page the scripts work should be completed i.e. `header('Location: page.php')` are you doing an `exit;` after your call to `header()`?

The `exit;` will stop execution of your script so the other script that you cannot change wont get the chance to attempt execution of another `header()` statement.